# Best way to convert Pascal Case to a sentence

Tags: c#, string

What is the best way to convert from Pascal Case (upper Camel Case) to a sentence.

For example starting with

```
"AwaitingFeedback"
```

and converting that to

```
"Awaiting feedback"
```

C# preferable but I could convert it from Java or similar.

Comment: Camel case is awaitingFeedback and not AwaitingFeedback (Pascal Case). Also, what you want to do is not completely possible. How about disableGPS? Is there a solution general enough to handle these cases?

Comment: @kgiannakakis altered the question accordingly. I always get forget which way round the names are, especially with there being upper and lower Camel Case.

Answer (score 81):

```
public static string ToSentenceCase(this string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + char.ToLower(m.Value[1]));
}
```

In versions of visual studio after 2015, you can do

```
public static string ToSentenceCase(this string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => $"{m.Value[0]} {char.ToLower(m.Value[1])}");
}
```

Based on: [Converting Pascal case to sentences using regular expression](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518114058/http://www.vojkovic.net/converting-pascal-case-to-sentences-using-regular-expression)

Comment: Unfortunately that link is dead now.

Comment: @Caltor Any time you find a dead link like that, you can use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/) to find a usable copy, assuming the site did not forbid it from being archived. I did that here. (Old Microsoft links tend to resolve themselves to updated URLs, but I tend to update links here on SO to the new URLs in case MS stop redirecting.)

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) for this. "Humanizer is a Portable Class Library that meets all your .NET needs for manipulating and displaying strings, enums, dates, times, timespans, numbers and quantities."

**Short Answer**

```
"AwaitingFeedback".Humanize() => Awaiting feedback
```

**Long and Descriptive Answer**

Humanizer can do a lot more work. Other examples are:

```
"PascalCaseInputStringIsTurnedIntoSentence".Humanize() => "Pascal case input string is turned into sentence"
"Underscored_input_string_is_turned_into_sentence".Humanize() => "Underscored input string is turned into sentence"
"Can_return_title_Case".Humanize(LetterCasing.Title) => "Can Return Title Case"
"CanReturnLowerCase".Humanize(LetterCasing.LowerCase) => "can return lower case"
```

Complete code is :

```
using Humanizer;
using static System.Console;

namespace HumanizerConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("AwaitingFeedback".Humanize());
            WriteLine("PascalCaseInputStringIsTurnedIntoSentence".Humanize());
            WriteLine("Underscored_input_string_is_turned_into_sentence".Humanize());
            WriteLine("Can_return_title_Case".Humanize(LetterCasing.Title));
            WriteLine("CanReturnLowerCase".Humanize(LetterCasing.LowerCase));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Awaiting feedback
> Pascal case input string is turned into sentence
> Underscored input string is turned into sentence
> Can Return Title Case
> can return lower case

If you prefer to write your own C# code you can achieve this by writing some C# code stuff as answered by others already.

Answer (score 16):

Here you go...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CamelCaseToString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CamelCaseToString("ThisIsYourMasterCallingYou"));   
        }

        private static string CamelCaseToString(string str)
        {
            if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
                return null;

            StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder(32);

            retVal.Append(char.ToUpper(str[0]));
            for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++ )
            {
                if (char.IsLower(str[i]))
                {
                    retVal.Append(str[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    retVal.Append(" ");
                    retVal.Append(char.ToLower(str[i]));
                }
            }

            return retVal.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ToUpper() the first character, otherwise your routine doesn't work with true camelCase, only PascalCase

Comment: Yup nice catch, I knew something was amiss (but couldn't put my finger on it) when he said "AwaitingFeedback" is camel case!

Answer (score 16):

**This works for me:**

```
Regex.Replace(strIn, "([A-Z]{1,2}|[0-9]+)", " $1").TrimStart()
```

Comment: How does this change the case of the letter after the space?

Comment: This may not return what you intend for cases like `AwaitingTFeedback` or `Awaiting9Feedback`. [Jef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432809/661933) is better for me (which returns `Awaiting T Feedback` and `Awaiting9 Feedback` respectively).

Answer (score 11):

**This is just like @SSTA, but is more efficient than calling TrimStart.**

```
Regex.Replace("ThisIsMyCapsDelimitedString", "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1")
```

Answer (score 10):

Found this in the MvcContrib source, doesn't seem to be mentioned here yet.

```
return Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", " $1", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just because everyone has been using Regex (except [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520553/1037948)), here's an implementation with `StringBuilder` that was about **5x faster** in my tests.  Includes checking for numbers too.

```
"SomeBunchOfCamelCase2".FromCamelCaseToSentence == "Some Bunch Of Camel Case 2"

public static string FromCamelCaseToSentence(this string input) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // start with the first character -- consistent camelcase and pascal case
    sb.Append(char.ToUpper(input[0]));

    // march through the rest of it
    for(var i = 1; i < input.Length; i++) {
        // any time we hit an uppercase OR number, it's a new word
        if(char.IsUpper(input[i]) || char.IsDigit(input[i])) sb.Append(' ');
        // add regularly
        sb.Append(input[i]);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In your benchmarks did you cache the regex object? There are "compiled regexes" but I'm not sure if .net uses them by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices

Answer (score 4):

Here's a basic way of doing it that I came up with using Regex

```
public static string CamelCaseToSentence(this string value)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var firstWord = true;

    foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(value, "([A-Z][a-z]+)|[0-9]+"))
    {
        if (firstWord)
        {
            sb.Append(match.ToString());
            firstWord = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(match.ToString().ToLower());
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It will also split off numbers which I didn't specify but would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
string camel = "MyCamelCaseString";
string s = Regex.Replace(camel, "([A-Z])", " $1").ToLower().Trim();
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(1));
```

Edit: didn't notice your casing requirements, modifed accordingly. You could use a matchevaluator to do the casing, but I think a substring is easier. You could also wrap it in a 2nd regex replace where you change the first character

```
"^\w"
```

to upper

```
\U (i think)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regex, inserting a space before each upper case character, then lowering all the string.

```
    string spacedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(yourString, "\B([A-Z])", " \k");
    spacedString = spacedString.ToLower();
```

Comment: I don't know C# but I don't think escapes like \s are legal in the replace section: how the language will know if it must insert space, tab or something else? :-)

Comment: You're right, should be simpler to replace it with a clear " ".

Comment: The only thing I'd say is that will produce "awaiting feedback"

Comment: Well you sure have to remove the first space and upper the first character. Maybe add a "\B" before the pattern so as not to match the first char.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do in JavaScript (or PHP, etc.) where you can define a function in the replace call:

```
var camel = "AwaitingFeedbackDearMaster";
var sentence = camel.replace(/([A-Z].)/g, function (c) { return ' ' + c.toLowerCase(); });
alert(sentence);
```

Although I haven't solved the initial cap problem... :-)

Now, for the Java solution:

```
String ToSentence(String camel)
{
  if (camel == null) return ""; // Or null...
  String[] words = camel.split("(?=[A-Z])");
  if (words == null) return "";
  if (words.length == 1) return words[0];
  StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder(camel.length());
  if (words[0].length() > 0) // Just in case of camelCase instead of CamelCase
  {
    sentence.append(words[0] + " " + words[1].toLowerCase());
  }
  else
  {
    sentence.append(words[1]);
  }
  for (int i = 2; i < words.length; i++)
  {
    sentence.append(" " + words[i].toLowerCase());
  }
  return sentence.toString();
}

System.out.println(ToSentence("AwaitingAFeedbackDearMaster"));
System.out.println(ToSentence(null));
System.out.println(ToSentence(""));
System.out.println(ToSentence("A"));
System.out.println(ToSentence("Aaagh!"));
System.out.println(ToSentence("stackoverflow"));
System.out.println(ToSentence("disableGPS"));
System.out.println(ToSentence("Ahh89Boo"));
System.out.println(ToSentence("ABC"));
```

Note the trick to split the sentence without loosing any character...

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

```
NewString = "";
Loop through every char of the string (skip the first one)
   If char is upper-case ('A'-'Z')
     NewString = NewString + ' ' + lowercase(char)
   Else
     NewString = NewString + char
```

Better ways can perhaps be done by using regex or by string replacement routines (replace 'X' with ' x')

Answer (score 1):

An xquery solution that works for both UpperCamel and lowerCamel case:

To output sentence case (only the first character of the first word is capitalized):

```
declare function content:sentenceCase($string)
{
let $firstCharacter := substring($string, 1, 1)
let $remainingCharacters := substring-after($string, $firstCharacter)
return
concat(upper-case($firstCharacter),lower-case(replace($remainingCharacters, '([A-Z])', ' $1')))
};
```

To output title case (first character of each word capitalized):

```
declare function content:titleCase($string)
{
let $firstCharacter := substring($string, 1, 1)
let $remainingCharacters := substring-after($string, $firstCharacter)
return
concat(upper-case($firstCharacter),replace($remainingCharacters, '([A-Z])', ' $1'))
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found myself doing something similar, and I appreciate having a point-of-departure with this discussion. This is my solution, placed as an extension method to the string class in the context of a console application.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string piratese = "avastTharMatey";
            string ivyese = "CheerioPipPip";

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n", piratese.CamelCaseToString(), ivyese.CamelCaseToString());
            Console.WriteLine("For Pete\'s sake, man, hit ENTER!");
            string strExit = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string CamelCaseToString(this string str)
        {
            StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder(32);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                string strTrimmed = str.Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTrimmed))
                {
                    retVal.Append(char.ToUpper(strTrimmed[0]));

                    if (strTrimmed.Length > 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < strTrimmed.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (char.IsUpper(strTrimmed[i])) retVal.Append(" ");

                            retVal.Append(char.ToLower(strTrimmed[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the preceding answers split acronyms and numbers, adding a space in front of each character. I wanted acronyms and numbers to be kept together so I have a simple state machine that emits a space every time the input transitions from one state to the other.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a space before any capitalized letter (but not for a run of capitals or numbers)
    /// </summary>
    internal static string FromCamelCaseToSentence(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return String.Empty;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool upper = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            bool isUpperOrDigit = char.IsUpper(input[i]) || char.IsDigit(input[i]);
            // any time we transition to upper or digits, it's a new word
            if (!upper && isUpperOrDigit)
            {
                sb.Append(' ');
            }
            sb.Append(input[i]);
            upper = isUpperOrDigit;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And here's some tests:

```
    [TestCase(null, ExpectedResult = "")]
    [TestCase("", ExpectedResult = "")]
    [TestCase("ABC", ExpectedResult = "ABC")]
    [TestCase("abc", ExpectedResult = "abc")]
    [TestCase("camelCase", ExpectedResult = "camel Case")]
    [TestCase("PascalCase", ExpectedResult = "Pascal Case")]
    [TestCase("Pascal123", ExpectedResult = "Pascal 123")]
    [TestCase("CustomerID", ExpectedResult = "Customer ID")]
    [TestCase("CustomABC123", ExpectedResult = "Custom ABC123")]
    public string CanSplitCamelCase(string input)
    {
        return FromCamelCaseToSentence(input);
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer. In my project I added `bool nextIsLower = i > 0 && i + 1 < source.Length && char.IsLower(source[i + 1]);` and changed the if expression to `if ((!upper || nextIsLower) && isUpperOrDigit)`. This separates acronyms from words, so **CustomABCWith123** becomes **Custom ABC With 123** instead of **Custom ABCWith 123**. There may be cases I haven't handled, and, of course, A and I don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters#272929)

Small chage to the accepted answer, to convert the second and subsequent Capitalised letters to lower case, so change

```
if (char.IsUpper(text[i]))                
    newText.Append(' ');            
newText.Append(text[i]);
```

to

```
if (char.IsUpper(text[i]))                
{
    newText.Append(' ');            
    newText.Append(char.ToLower(text[i]));
}
else
   newText.Append(text[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. This is the fastest that I got while avoiding creating spaces for abbreviations.

```
public static string PascalCaseToSentence(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input.Length < 2)
            return input;

        var sb = new char[input.Length + ((input.Length + 1) / 2)];
        var len = 0;
        var lastIsLower = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var current = input[i];
            if (current < 97)
            {
                if (lastIsLower)
                {
                    sb[len] = ' ';
                    len++;
                }
                lastIsLower = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lastIsLower = true;
            }
            sb[len] = current;

            len++;
        }

        return new string(sb, 0, len);
    }
```