# Get the Index of Upper Case letter from a String

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An algorithm to "spacify" CamelCased strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484085/an-algorithm-to-spacify-camelcased-strings)

I have a string like this: `MyUnsolvedProblem`

I want to modify the string like this: `My Unsolved Problem`

How can I do that? I have tried using Regex with no luck!

Comment: to get only index look https://stackoverflow.com/a/51183419/4871015

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("MyUnsolvedProblem", @"(\p{Lu})", " $1").TrimStart();
```

Without regex:

```
var s = "MyUnsolvedProblem";
var result = string.Concat(s.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) ? $" {c}" : c.ToString()))
        .TrimStart();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace("MyUnsolvedProblem", "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ based approach:

```
string data = "TestStringData";
var converted = data.Select(x => Char.IsUpper(x) ? String.Concat(" ", x) : x.ToString());
var singleString = converted.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a suggestion of how to do it in C# if that helps:

```
String PreString = "getAllItemsByID";

System.Text.StringBuilder SB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (Char C in PreString)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(C))
        SB.Append(' ');
    SB.Append(C);
}

Response.Write(SB.ToString());
```

I'm sure that there is a way to do it with regular expressions too, but this is one option.