# How to find the capital substring of a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find the capitalized portion of a string, to then insert two characters that represent the Double Capital sign in the Braille language. My intention for doing this is to design a translator that can translate from regular text to Braille.
I'll give an example belo.
English String: My variable is of type IEnumerable.
Braille: ,My variable is of type ,,IE-numberable.
I also want the dash in IE-numerable to only break words that have upper and lower case, but not in front of punctuation marks, white spaces, numbers or other symbols.

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to loop through the characters in a string? How to check whether a character is uppercase? How to aggregate the results?

Comment: I am trying to find the capital letters of a string like this one:

Comment: Basically, I am trying to find the capitalized portion of, say myVARIABLE or IEnumerable. I then want to take that portion of the string and insert ",,", which is the double-cap signs in the Braille language, so the string would look like this: ,,Ie-numerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had never heard of a "Double Capital" sign, so I read up on it [here](http://www.brl.org/ebae/rule02.html). From what I can tell, this should suit your needs.

You can use this to find any sequence of two or more uppercase (majuscule) Latin letters or hyphens in your string:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "[A-Z-]{2,}");
```

You can use this to insert the double-capital sign:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Z-]{2,}", ",,$0");
```

For example:

```
var input = "this is a TEST";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Z-]{2,}", ",,$0"); // this is a ,,TEST
```

You can use this to hand single and double capitals:

```
var input = "McGRAW-HILL";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-Z-]([A-Z-]+)?", 
        m => (m.Groups[1].Success ? ",," : ",") + m.Value); // ,Mc,,GRAW-HILL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to write up this answer. I greatly appreciate it. I really do.

Comment: @user2227354 Glad to help. Here's a tip for asking questions on SO: always show what you've tried and explain why it didn't work (error, bad result, etc.). For questions asking for regular expression patterns, it's **critical** to show what input strings you want to match and what strings you don't want to match, and in the case regular expression replacements, please show at least a few input strings with their desired outputs. That will help you avoid down votes and close votes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them with a simple regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ..snip..

Regex r = new Regex("[A-Z]"); // This will capture only upper case characters
Match m = r.Match(input, 0);
```

The variable `m` of type [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) will contain a collection of captures. If only the first match matters, you can check its [`Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) property directly.

Now you can insert the characters you want in that position, using [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx):

```
input = input.Insert(m.Index, doubleCapitalSign);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are going for?

```
var inputString = string.Empty; //Your input string here
var output = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var c in inputString.ToCharArray())
{
    if (char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        output.AppendFormat("_{0}_", c);
    }
    else
    {
        output.Append(c);
    }
}
```

This will loop through each character in the `inputString` if the characater is upper it inserts a `_` before and after (replace that with your desired braille characters) otherwise appends the character to the output.

Answer (score 0):

this code can solve your problema

```
        string x = "abcdEFghijkl";
        string capitalized = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i].ToString() == x[i].ToString().ToUpper())
                capitalized += x[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the method **Char.IsUpper** method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s91f3by.aspx

This is another similar question that uses that method to solve a similar problem
[Get the Index of Upper Case letter from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997618/get-the-index-of-upper-case-letter-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the first index of an uppercase letter:

```
var firstUpperCharIndex = text  // <-- a string
    .Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => Char.IsUpper(x.chr));
if (firstUpperCharIndex != null)
{ 
    text = text.Insert(firstUpperCharIndex.index, ",,");
}
```