# Character Replacement In LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I was trying to put together a solution to:
[Insert spaces between words on a camel-cased token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796383/insert-spaces-between-words-on-a-camel-cased-token)

Essentially, he wants to turn 'ThisIsATest' into 'This Is A Test'.  I thought, 'Oh, that's easy, I can do it with LINQ' but I struggled with it.

Can someone help me?

```
Dim s As String = String.Join("", From myChar As Char In myStr _
                                  Select If(Char.IsUpper(myChar), (" " & myChar).ToString, myChar.ToString))
```

Is the path I started to go down, but I'm having trouble getting the results into something I can work with.  I even added the .ToString to try and get back an array of Strings, but I'm still getting an error.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.String]'
>   to type 'System.String[]'.

I believe that means I'm getting a collection of System.Char, System.String instead of just a System.String like I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is a related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323314/best-way-to-convert-pascal-case-to-a-sentence. There are quite a few different options there to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Seeing it done correctly, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the second parameter to String[]. You can use `.ToArray()`

```
Dim outStr As String = String.Join("", (From myChar As Char In myStr _
                                               Select If(Char.IsUpper(myChar), (" " & myChar).ToString, myChar.ToString)).ToArray())
```

Comment: You have a space in front of the test string.

Comment: @IAbstract - My plan was to .Trim the whole thing rather than try to deal with the edge case of the initial capital letter; but you are 100% correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can use RegEx and split on the uppercase characters.

```
Dim myString as string = "ThisIsATest"
Dim outStr As String = Regex.Replace(myString,"[A-Z]"," $0")
```

The case-sensitive replace will locate every uppercase character and insert a space in front of the character.

Comment: +1: Although not LINQ, this is a much cleaner. I would take this over a LINQ solution for readability.

Comment: @Chuck Savage - that is a good question.  It depends on what the purpose is and is definitely something to consider during an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

C#:

```
var myStr = "TestString";
var outStr = string.Concat(myStr.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) ? " " + c : c.ToString()));
```

auto-translated to VB.NET:

```
Dim myStr = "TestString"
Dim outStr = String.Concat(myStr.[Select](Function(c) If(Char.IsUpper(c), " " & Convert.ToString(c), c.ToString())))
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the C# solution, but the VB.Net solution is returning: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.String
]