# REGEX: Appending Single Space between Capitals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I got some idea from a [C# related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters), but I need it in Javascript.  I am try all sorts of things, it doesn't seem to work.

```
name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, / $&/);
```

What I am trying to do is make:

> ```
> FirstName
> ```

with spaces:

> ```
> First Name
> ```

But what I get is:

> / F/irst/ N/ame

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried all answers in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"FirstName".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

That results in

```
First Name
```

Without a leading space.

Comment: Though, this obviously only works for names with a-z, not any foreign names.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&')
```

The second parameter need not be a regex, but a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` from the replace section. Some languages need them, some don't.

Comment: That fails to be interpreted.  By the engine.