# Add spacing between lowercase and uppercase?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to add a space when an uppercase character or an underscore is in the string.

How do I do this?

***EXAMPLE 1***

**Input**

```
ThisIsAnInputString
```

**Output (result)**

```
This Is An Input String
```

***EXAMPLE 2***

**Input**

```
This_Is_An_Input_String
```

**Output (result)**

```
This Is An Input String
```

Comment: In the first case it is a bit tricky but I would go for the ASCII solution since there is the place to look for difference of 'U' from 'u' in second case it is just char replacement.
If going for the ascii just cast char by char to int and you will get it. Here is the link to the actual ascii table : http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table

Sorry for not giving the solution itself but the question was how...

Comment: Try this for spaces : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters

Answer (score 14):

You can use a regular expression that matches a lower case character followed by an upper case character, with an optional underscore between:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z])_?([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

You might want to use this to handle single character words also:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<!^)_?([A-Z])", " $1");
```

Comment: +1, I might change `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` to handle strings like `ThisIsATest` though.

Comment: Hrrm, can you give me an example of when it would work better?  Sorry, my regex is pretty weak.

Comment: Your own example. Come to think of it `[a-z]?` should suffice. I.e: `Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z]?)_?([A-Z])", "$1 $2")`. `This_Is_A_Test` would with your example not yield a desired result.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: That would add a space before the first character.

Comment: @Guffa: And according to specifications this would be correct. From OP: `add a space when an uppercase character`. That would include the first character aswell.

Comment: Actually my example doesn't suffice either. If the input string is already in the correct state my example will fail. `([a-z]?)[_^ ]?([A-Z])` however should work.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: I don't think that was the intention. If you go strictly by the description, the output of the second example would be `" This _ Is _ An _ Input _ String"`.

Comment: @Guffa: "Good intentions pave the way to hell" ;) Jokes aside, I cannot see how the second example would become what you say. See my answer for test cases.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: The description says to add a space when an uppercase character or an underscore is in the string. That would mean to add a space before underscores just like before uppercase characters. The second example has both uppercase characters and underscores, so there would be spaces before both of them.

Comment: @Guffa: Aaah... You meant the OPs' second example and not mine. Yes. I agree. But still. Yours (and Abes) will still fail. Even on the example Abe brought up.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: Why do you think that they fail?

Comment: @Guffa: Since `ThisIsATest` will with both yours and Abes solution yield "This Is ATest". `This_Is_A_Test` would yield `This Is A_Test`.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: Ah, I see what you mean. Using a negative look-behind would solve that.

Comment: @Guffa: Almost perfect but still an already correct string will fail, `This Is A Test`. A string with a leading underscore will also fail, `_This_Is_A_Test`.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: I can't see that OP has any need for that. You can always find strings where the result might be unwanted, like an acronym that gets spaced; `AnSQLQuery` becomes `An S Q L Query` rather than `An SQL Query`.

Answer (score 6):

Underscores:

```
string inputString = "This_Is_An_Input_String";
string resultString = inputString.Replace('_', ' ');
```

Capitals:

```
string inputString = "ThisIsAnInputString";
//this will put a space before all capitals that are preceded by a lowercase character
string resultString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your specifications you want to add a space before any uppercase character. This should also apply for the first letter aswell. All underscores should be replaced with a space. Most answers here omit the first space (before `This`).

```
var pattern = "([a-z?])[_ ]?([A-Z])";

var input = "ThisIsATest";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 $2");
// output = " This Is A Test"

var input = "This_Is_A_Test";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 $2");
// output = " This Is A Test"

var input = "ThisIsAnInputString";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 $2");
// output = " This Is An Input String"

var input = "This_Is_An_Input_String";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 $2");
// output = " This Is An Input String"
```

If you do not want the *extra* space in the beginning then use [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var input = "This_Is_A_Test";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1 $2").TrimStart(' ');
// output = "This Is A Test"
```

**Edit (updated):**

I've compiled the different regex suggestions into a small test application to verify the results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  const string expectedResult = "This Is A Test";
  var samples = new string[][]
      {
        new [] {"This Is A Test", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"ThisIsATest", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"This_Is_A_Test", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"ThisIsA_Test", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"This_IsATest", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"_ThisIsATest", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"_This_Is_A_Test", "This Is A Test"},
        new [] {"Thi_s_Is_A_Test", "Thi s Is A Test"},
        new [] {"T hi_s_Is_A_Te s_ t", "T hi s Is A Te s  t"}
      };

  foreach (var input in samples)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(input[0] + " => " + input[1]);

    // Guffa 1 1/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("Guffa 1:         " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"([a-z])_?([A-Z])", "$1 $2") == input[1]));

    // Guffa 2 4/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("Guffa 2:         " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"(?<!^)_?([A-Z])", " $1") == input[1]));

    // Abe Miesler 1/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("Abe Miesler:     " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"([a-zA-Z])_?([A-Z])", "$1 $2") == input[1]));

    // AppDeveloper 2/9 correct. (Not entirely fair since it was not meant for underscores).
    Console.WriteLine("AppDeveloper:    " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"_([A-Z])", " $1") == input[1]));

    // sparky68967 1/9 correct. (Not entirely fair since it was not meant for underscores).
    Console.WriteLine("sparky68967:     " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2") == input[1]));

    // p.s.w.g 4/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("p.s.w.g:         " + (Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input[0], @"([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])", "$1_$2"), "_", " ") == input[1]));

    // Sani Huttunen 1 7/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("Sani Huttunen 1: " + (Regex.Replace(input[0], @"([a-z]?)[_ ]?([A-Z])", "$1 $2").TrimStart(' ') == input[1]));

    // Sani Huttunen 2 9/9 correct.
    Console.WriteLine("Sani Huttunen 2: " + (Regex.Replace(input[0].Replace('_', ' '), @"(?<!^)[ ]?([A-Z])", " $1").TrimStart(' ') == input[1]));

    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you replace the `^` character?

Answer (score 0):

For Input type : `ThisIsAnInputString`

```
        string input1 = "ThisIsAnInputString";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in input1)
        {
            if (Char.IsUpper(c))
            {
                builder.Append(' ');
                builder.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
        }

        string output = builder.ToString().Trim();
```

For Input type : `This_Is_An_Input_String`

```
string input2 = "This_Is_An_Input_String";
string output = Regex.Replace(input2, "_([A-Z])", " $1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // check if string is empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return string.Empty;


        if (input.Contains('_'))
        {
            return input.Replace('_', ' ');
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Char char1 in input)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(char1))
                    newString.Append(new char[] { ' ', char1 });
                else
                    newString.Append(char1);
            }

            newString.Remove(0, 1);
            return newString.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "ThisIsAnInputString";
        String str2 = "This_Is_An_Input_String";

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(str2);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        str.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(c => sb.Append(c == '_' ? " " :  char.IsLower(c) ? c.ToString() : " " + c.ToString()));
        str2.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(c => sb2.Append(c == '_' ? " " : char.IsLower(c) ? c.ToString() : " " + c.ToString()));

        str = sb.ToString().Trim(" ".ToCharArray());
        str2 = sb2.ToString().Trim(" ".ToCharArray());

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(str2);



        Console.Read();
    }
```