# How to convert Pascal Case with Numbers to a sentence?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to convert a Pascal Case string with numbers to a sentence:

```
OpenHouse2StartTimestamp = > Open House 2 Start Timestamp
```

I've been able to use regex to separate them without numbers, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211435/9382), but how to do so when numbers are present is eluding me:

```
string sentence = Regex.Replace(label, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + m.Value[1]);
```

How can I add numbers into the mix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946933/add-spacing-between-lowercase-and-uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var sentence = Regex.Replace(label, @"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)", " ");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D%5BA-Z%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D%5CD%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5CD%29%28%3F%3D%5Cd%29&i=OpenHouse2StartTimestamp&r=%20). The regex matches:

- `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|` - a location between a lower- and an uppercase ASCII letters, or
- `(?<=\d)(?=\D)|` - a location between a digit and a non-digit, or
- `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` - a location between a non-digit and a digit.

Since all you need is inserting a space at the positions matched, you do not need a Match evaluator, just use a string replacement pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explainer.  Makes sense now that I see it.