# In Regex, how do to add one extra space between every word starting with Capital

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string: `CategoryName`

I need to add space between `Category` and `Name`.

So I have to insert a space before each capital letter.

Comment: Regex may be too slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters?rq=1

Comment: What about `SimpleHTTPRequest`? Do you really want that to become `Simple H T T P Request`? Shouldn't it be `Simple HTTP Request`?

Comment: My answer supports Tim's point, but also what should happen if there are numbers? e.g. `MyCategory1` or `MyCategory2Fish`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var input = "CategoryName";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z])([A-Z])", @"$1 $2"); //Category Name
```

UPDATE (this will treat sequence of capital letters as one word)

```
var input = "SimpleHTTPRequest";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z]|[A-Z]{2,})([A-Z])", @"$1 $2");
//Simple HTTP Request
```

Comment: As Tim has pointed out, what about `SimpleHTTPRequest`. This answer would give `Simple HTTPRequest` shouldn't it give `Simple HTTP Request`

Comment: What about `HaveAGo` ?

Comment: @BobVale that will produce `Have AGo`, but it's not clear if `AGo` should be split. E.g. we don't need to split `HTTP` into `H T T P`. BTW that's why I always write unit tests for code that involves RegEx :)

Comment: yes but HTTP all the letters are caps whereas AGo has a lowercase o

Answer (score 4):

This code will do the job

```
var source = "CategoryName";
var nameConvert = new Regex(@"((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|(?<!^|\s)[A-Z][a-z])");
var converted = nameConvert.Replace(source, " $1");
```

This will leave multiple capital letters together e.g. `FearTheCIAReally` becomes `Fear The CIA Really`

To explain the regex:

- `(` start capture group $1
- `(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]` capital letter preceded by a lower case letter (don't capture lower case)
- `|` or
- `(?<!^|\s)` preceding character not space or start of string, but don't capture
- `[A-Z]` capital letter
- `[a-z]` followed by a lower case letter
- `)` end capture group 1

I actually have this as a library function I use all the time

```
public static class StringExtensions {

   private static readonly Regex NameConvert =
                new Regex(@"((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|(?<!^|\s)[A-Z][a-z])");

   public static string ToDisplayFormat(this string name) {
     return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? 
       String.Empty :
       NameConvert.Replace(name," $1");
   }
}
```

And then I can just use it in code

```
var name="CategoryName";
var displayName = name.ToDisplayFormat();
```

Comment: +1 from me, that should be an answer!

Comment: BTW looks like you don't need last group for lower case letters - you can simply use `((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|(?<!^|\s)[A-Z][a-z])`. But answer anyway very nice

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Good point, I was so busy concentrating on making sure I only matched the capital letter that I didn't consider that it's ok to include the following lowercase because the match works using look behind. I'll update

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Any reason you removed the readonly on the field?

Comment: @BobValue I was adding variable type name, that you missed. And new string `private static readonly Regex` was too long, so I removed non important part to get rid of slider from code window - it's not convenient to scroll to the right to see the code (actually most important part of it). You can split assignment in two lines, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z?])[_ ]?([a-z])
```

Try this Regular expression.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will match A-Z or a ? followed by an optional space or underscore followed by a-z

Comment: A-Z since capital condtion is there in question

Comment: but what are you expecting the `?` in `[A-Z?]` to do.  The OP has asked for a method to insert spaces but you haven't shown them how to use the Regex to do this.