# How to add whitepaces between each capital letter?

Tags: java, regex

I try to write a regular expression in order to:

1. Add white spaces between each capital letter.
2. Remove all numbers.

I have the text: `ClassNameOne839`, and I want to get the text: `Class Name One`

There is a library function which do it? or any regular expression?

Comment: i doubt that there is a library for that. try to write the regex and we might help you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/272633/2006839

Comment: String s = MyDocumentFileIsHere;
String textWithSpace = s.replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
holder.titleTxt.setText(textWithSpace);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) calls like this:

```
String text = "ClassNameOne839";
String cleanText = text.replaceAll("\\d+", "").replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

This first removes all numbers, and then adds a space before all upper-case letters that are not at the beginning of the `String`. `$1` and `$2` are references to the first and second *groups* of the regex.

Comment: In case you want to preserve numbers and Google brought you here, try this:  

    String cleanText = text.replaceAll("(.)([A-Z0-9]\\w)", "$1 $2");

Output: "Class Name One 839"

Answer (score 2):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase
```

Does almost everything you need ;)
Try this one:

```
cleanText = StringUtils.join(StringUtils.splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase(in.replaceAll("\\d+", "")), " ");
```

Should be much faster than regexps.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression `[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z\s\b0-9])` Would match each individual capitalized word followed by another capital letter, a space character or digit. Simply print each result in a row with a space behind it and you're set

Edit: This is ofcourse given that your capitalized names don't contain weird characters, the use would be something like this:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z\s\b0-9])").matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
   string = string + matcher.group();
}
Sytem.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = "ClassName399".replaceAll("\\d", "").replaceAll("([A-Z])", "$1 ");
```

The first expression will detect all integers in the string (`\\d`) and delete them, the second looks for any capital letter (using the range operator `[]`) and then takes what you found `$1` and adds a space after it.

Please refer to Java [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class for more info on regular expressions.