# How to use System.Net.HttpRequestHeader enum with an ASP.NET request?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, http-headers

In WCF (System.Net.WebHeaderCollection) a header value can be retreived using either the System.Net.HttpRequestHeader enum or a header string:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[httpRequestHeaderEnum] 
// or
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get(rawHeaderString)
```

But in ASP.NET, the headers are in a NameValueCollection which only accepts a header string:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[rawHeaderString]
```

In order to use the Enum's for ASP.NET, where is the map from enum System.Net.HttpRequestHeader to its header string?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a mapping method? For reference:
[HttpRequestHeader enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httprequestheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could just make a mapping table, or **Using code swiped from [Binary Worrier's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters?answertab=active#tab-top)**, you could do something like this:

```
public static string TranslateToHttpHeaderName(HttpRequestHeader enumToTranslate)
{
    const string httpHeaderNameSeparator = "-";
    string enumName = enumToTranslate.ToString();
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // skip first letter
    stringBuilder.Append(enumName[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < enumName.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(enumName[i])) stringBuilder.Append(httpHeaderNameSeparator);
        stringBuilder.Append(enumName[i]);
    }
    // Cover special case for 2 character enum name "Te" to "TE" header case.
    string headerName = stringBuilder.ToString();
    if (headerName.Length == 2) headerName = headerName.ToUpper();
    return headerName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default implementation, using a WebHeaderCollection

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HttpRequestHeader, string> ToStringKeyCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<HttpRequestHeader, string>();
    public static string ToStringKey(this HttpRequestHeader enumToEvaluate)
    {
        var str = ToStringKeyCache.GetOrAdd(enumToEvaluate, header =>
        {
            var nm = new WebHeaderCollection();
            nm.Set(header, "X");
            return nm.AllKeys.Single();
        });
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Unless I completely misunderstood your question:

- Import the `System.Net` namespace: `using System.Net;`

e.g. WebForms:

```
using System.Net

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Single - e.g. Connection 
    FooLabel.Text = Request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Connection.ToString()] + "<hr />";

    //Go through all
    foreach (var en in Enum.GetNames(typeof(HttpRequestHeader)))
    {
        FooLabel.Text += en + " : " + Request.Headers[en] + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Hth...

Comment: The problem is that some of the names have dashes ("-") in them.  For instance, in your example, "Accept" works but "Accept-Encoding" does not.