# C# regex to convert camelCase to Sentence case

Tags: c#, regex

In my example
`var key = new CultureInfo("en-GB").TextInfo.(item.Key)` produces, 'Camelcase' what regular expression could I add that would produce a space before the second 'c' ?

Examples:

'camelCase' > 'Camel case'

'itIsTimeToStopNow' > 'It is time to stop now'

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the ways how you can do it.

```
string input = "itIsTimeToStopNow";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\p{Lu}", m => " " + m.Value.ToLowerInvariant());
output = char.ToUpperInvariant(output[0]) + output.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Both answers worked perfectly but I will probably go with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to replace capital letters with space capital letters then make the first character uppercase:

```
var input = "itIsTimeToStopNow";

// add spaces, lower case and turn into a char array so we 
// can manipulate individual characters
var spaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"[A-Z]", " $0").ToLower.ToCharArray();

// spaced = { 'i', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', ... }

// replace first character with its uppercase equivalent
spaced[0] = spaced[0].ToString().ToUpper()[0];

// spaced = { 'I', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', ... }

// combine the char[] back into a string
var result = String.Concat(spaced);

// result = "It is time to stop now"
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly, it was first and had explanatory notes so I have up voted it. however the other solution seemed to use a bit less code when I integrated it into my page.