# .net core entity framework (EF Core) table naming convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

.net core entity framework (EF Core) table naming convention plural to single/simple/underscore

Being a fan of `single simple underscore` naming convention to table names, I feel uncomfortable with the way **EF core** is naming tables `Plural PascalCase`.

**Model**

```
public class SourceType {
   ...
```

**DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<SourceType> SourceTypes { get; set; }
    ...
```

This creates the table with the name `SourceTypes` *(PascalCase and Plural)*

I know I can change the generated table name by using `[table('source_type')]` in the model class.

But, what I need is a method to do it in global manner.

Comment: The latest EF Core revision uses the name used in your context as your tablename, so if you write `DbSet<SourceType> MyTableName` your table won't be called Sourcetypes, but it'll be called `MyTableName`. While this isn't an automation like you want, it is handy to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In short**

Extend ModelBuilder with an extension method, do some regex, and call the method in you DbContext

Edited: You can also use this 3rd party [library](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions) `EFCore.NamingConventions`

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      => optionsBuilder
        .UseNpgsql(...)
        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
```

**In Detail**

Create an extension for `ModelBuilder` class

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions 
{
    public static void SetSimpleUnderscoreTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {                        
            Regex underscoreRegex = new Regex(@"((?<=.)[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)|((?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+)");            
            entity.Relational().TableName = underscoreRegex.Replace(entity.DisplayName(), @"_$1$2").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method in you `DbContext`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SourceType> SourceTypes { get; set; }
    ...
   
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        ...
        builder.SetSimpleUnderscoreTableNameConvention();
    }
}
```

*I hope this will help any developers like me not to waste time searching for the solution. :)*

Answer (score 17):

I know the question is old and has been answered, but this NuGet [(EFCore.NamingConventions)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFCore.NamingConventions/) could be interesting.

This is a NuGet package that handles the naming convention as simple as

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseNpgsql(...)
        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
```

It also supports:

- UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention: `FullName` becomes `full_name`
- UseLowerCaseNamingConvention: `FullName` becomes `fullname`
- UseCamelCaseNamingConvention: `FullName` becomes `fullName`
- UseUpperCaseNamingConvention: `FullName` becomes `FULLNAME`

Comment: You are absolutely right, @AndreaBlengino.

Answer (score 1):

Faraj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540685/3009578) not works on `ThreeCapitalWords`, result is `three_capitalwords`.

Here is my solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272929/3009578):

```
    /// <summary>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="preserveAcronyms">If true, 'PrepareXXRecord' converted to 'prepare_xx_record',
    /// otherwise to 'prepare_xxrecord'</param>
    public static void SetSimpleUnderscoreTableNameConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, bool preserveAcronyms)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var underscored = AddUndercoresToSentence(entity.DisplayName(), preserveAcronyms);
            entity.Relational().TableName = underscored.ToLower();
        }
    }

    private static string AddUndercoresToSentence(string text, bool preserveAcronyms)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            return string.Empty;
        var newText = new StringBuilder(text.Length * 2);
        newText.Append(text[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(text[i]))
                if ((text[i - 1] != '_' && !char.IsUpper(text[i - 1])) ||
                    (preserveAcronyms && char.IsUpper(text[i - 1]) &&
                     i < text.Length - 1 && !char.IsUpper(text[i + 1])))
                    newText.Append('_');
            newText.Append(text[i]);
        }
        return newText.ToString();
    }
```

It also converts acronyms: `PrepareXXRecord` to `prepare_xx_record`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL&DR**:  The SnakeCase Solution does NOT work for Identity Framework; Manually create them using the method below;

**Explanation**: The SnakeCase() function works for the majority of issues. However, there are times where this method will not format your database tables correctly. One very popular example is the Identity Framework.  In those cases, it's recommended that you manually name the tables;

**FIX**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Configure default schema
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("asp_net_users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("asp_net_user_tokens");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("asp_net_user_logins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("asp_net_user_claims");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("asp_net_roles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("asp_net_user_roles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("asp_net_role_claims");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core 6, you can use the below extensions on the `ModelBuilder`:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyNamingConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var modelEntityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();

        foreach (var tableConfiguration in modelEntityTypes)
        {
            // Table Naming
            tableConfiguration.SetTableName(tableConfiguration.GetTableName().ToLowerUnderscoreName());

            // Column Naming
            var columnsProperties = tableConfiguration.GetProperties();

            foreach (var columnsProperty in columnsProperties)
            {
                var isOwnedProperty = columnsProperty.DeclaringEntityType.IsOwned();

                if (isOwnedProperty && columnsProperty.IsPrimaryKey())
                    continue;

                if (isOwnedProperty)
                {
                    var ownership = columnsProperty.DeclaringEntityType.FindOwnership();
                    var ownershipName = ownership.PrincipalToDependent.Name;
                    var columnName = $"{ownershipName}_{columnsProperty.Name}";
                    columnsProperty.SetColumnName(columnName.ToLowerUnderscoreName());
                }
                else
                {
                    columnsProperty.SetColumnName(columnsProperty.Name.ToLowerUnderscoreName());
                }
            }

            // Find primary key
            var pk = tableConfiguration.FindPrimaryKey();
            pk.SetName(pk.GetName().ToLowerUnderscoreName());

            // Foreign keys
            var fks = tableConfiguration.GetForeignKeys();

            foreach (var fk in fks)
            {
                var fkName = fk.GetConstraintName().ToLowerUnderscoreName();
                fk.SetConstraintName(fkName);
            }

            // Indexes
            var idxs = tableConfiguration.GetIndexes();

            foreach (var idx in idxs)
            {
                idx.SetDatabaseName(idx.GetDatabaseName().ToLowerUnderscoreName());
            }
        }
    }
        
    public static string ToLowerUnderscoreName(this string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return text;
        }

        var builder = new StringBuilder(text.Length + Math.Min(2, text.Length / 5));
        var previousCategory = default(UnicodeCategory?);

        for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < text.Length; currentIndex++)
        {
            var currentChar = text[currentIndex];

            if (currentChar == '_')
            {
                builder.Append('_');
                previousCategory = null;
                continue;
            }

            var currentCategory = char.GetUnicodeCategory(currentChar);

            switch (currentCategory)
            {
                case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
                case UnicodeCategory.TitlecaseLetter:
                    if (previousCategory == UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator ||
                            previousCategory == UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter ||
                            previousCategory != UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber &&
                            previousCategory != null &&
                            currentIndex > 0 &&
                            currentIndex + 1 < text.Length &&
                            char.IsLower(text[currentIndex + 1]))
                    {
                        builder.Append('_');
                    }

                    currentChar = char.ToLower(currentChar, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    break;

                case UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter:
                case UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber:
                    if (previousCategory == UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator)
                    {
                        builder.Append('_');
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    if (previousCategory != null)
                    {
                        previousCategory = UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator;
                    }
                    continue;
            }

            builder.Append(currentChar);
            previousCategory = currentCategory;
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in the `DbContext`, I have:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyNamingConvention();
    }
```