# Format C# string to match specific outcome

Tags: c#

I'm struggling with formatting a string. When my value is like: `OrderLineId` and want to format this to: `order_line_id`. All lowercase and each uppercase char should be appended with a `_` except the first character.

I do see some use of `TextInfo` of the `using System.Globalization;` but I can't get my head to fix this.

I try to fix this with just C# code, rather not Regex.... sorry

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `new String(text.SelectMany(x => char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString()).ToArray()).TrimStart('_')` work for you?

Comment: Try following :             string input = "OrderLineId";
            string output = input.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + string.Join("", input.Skip(1).Select(x => char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + char.ToLower(x).ToString() : x.ToString()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this question:

[Add spaces before Capital Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272633/add-spaces-before-capital-letters)

I have tweaked the answer for your purpose.

```
string AddUnderScoresToSentence(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            return "";
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(text.Length * 2);
        newText.Append(text[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(text[i]) && text[i - 1] != '_')
                newText.Append('_');
            newText.Append(text[i]);
        }
        string result = newText.ToString();
        return result.ToLower();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, looks easier then I thought! The weekend project can continue :)